# Spartacus header slots not respect the configuration

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I made the following configuration in the Spartacus Module Configuration:

```
 layoutSlots: {
        header: {
          slots: ['MiniCart'],
        },
        footer: {
          slots: []
        },
        LandingPage2Template: {
          slots: []
        }
      }
```

It correctly removes the footer and the content of the layout, but doesn't remove the header. It renders it fully, completely ignoring the configuration. Refer to this [documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/page-layout/). It's a bug or I made some mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a unfortunate result of a feature ;) Any custom configuration is deeply merged with the Spartacus default config.

In this case, you likely use the B2cStorefrontModule, which comes with a default layout config for the header. In the default header config, however, specific slot configurations are added for some breakpoints:

```
  header: {
    lg: { 
      slots: [x, y, z]
    }
  }
```

The resulting (merged) config, will contain both the default config for the lg breakpoint, and your custom header slots.

The LayoutService will take the right slots based on the breakpoint. Hence you likely don't see the changes in desktop mode (i'm guessing smaller screens work).

2 ways to fix it:

- don't use the `B2cStorefrontModule`, but use the `StorefrontModule` instead. This one doesn't provide a layout config at all
- override also the `lg` configuration, i.e. `lg: {slots: []}`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that out! I achieve the desired results by replacing the header using Outlets. It seems to me that is the right choice, considering that the structure I’m making is quite different from the layout delivered by default. I wander if it’s usual (and good) practice to replace the reader with my custom one, using the page slog component (<cx-page-slot>) to structure it in the way I need. Sorry if it’s another question, but to me this approach sounds better than using the slot configuration, although I understand that their intent and purpose are very different.